# Filter the arraylist related with LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have no idea to filter the arraylist related with Map.

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> g_nodes = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

*I used LinkedHashMap in my program.

After inserted the data from sql, g_nodes is displayed in console as the followings:

```
g_nodes = [{100=test100}, {100=test100, 101=test101}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 103=test103}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 103=test103, 104=test104}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 103=test103, 104=test104, 105=test105}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 103=test103, 104=test104, 108=test108}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 103=test103, 106=test106}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 107=test107}, {100=test100, 999=test999}]
```

I want to filter the g_nodes to output in console as the followings:

```
g_nodes = [{100=test100}, {100=test100, 101=test101}, {100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102},{100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 103=test103, 104=test104, 105=test105, 108=test108, 106=test106},{100=test100, 101=test101, 102=test102, 107=test107}, {100=test100, 999=test999}]
```

pls teach me how can I get it?

Comment: What's the criteria with which you want to filter the items?

Comment: starts from level 4 (e.g: 100 101 102 103), if next lines's level 4 is the same as previous line's level 4, i want to add the value in one line.